# google pay intent chooser not called onActivityResult.?but phone pay and paytm is working fine in android

Tags: android, google-pay

Please reffer below code for more understanding..

```
Intent upiPayIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
       upiPayIntent.setData(uri);

       Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(upiPayIntent, "Pay with");

       if (null != chooser.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())) {
           Log.d("TAG", "UPI Payment resolved to activity");
           startActivityForResult(chooser, UPI_PAYMENT);
       } else {
           Log.d("TAG", "No activity found to handle UPI Payment");
       }
```

Comment: @sathis did you got the answer ? if yes can you post here. im also facing the same issue .